# Woocomnerce Limit Purchase value before proceed checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We are using woocommerce and We need to make the order total price to be limited more than 15 KD.

If a customer added items to the cart and the total price less than 15 he can't proceed to checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your current theme function.php file.

> METHOD 1:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_weight_requirements' );
function spyr_set_weight_requirements() {
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $total = WC()->cart->total;
        if( $total < 15 ){
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>MAXIMUM CART PRICE 15 FOR CHECKOUT</strong>','error');
        }
    }
}
```

> METHOD:2

```
function disable_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
    $total = WC()->cart->total;

    if( $total < 15 ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        echo '<a href="#" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">Proceed to checkout</a>';

    }  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout_button_no_shipping', 1 );
```

**In First method page redirect checkout but display only message.**

> METHOD 3:

```
function disable_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
    $total = WC()->cart->total;

    if( $total < 15 ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

    }  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout_button_no_shipping', 99 );
```

Comment: I need to remove the proceed to checkout if less than 15

Comment: Yes then you can use second method for this. Put this function your function.php file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work  Can you please check this 
 is for our cart with order 4  and checkout button still not removed https://i.imgur.com/cdBTYHK.png

Comment: kindly check it

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Patel for your appreciated answer I used css yesterday to solve it using display:none